# Create a vertical Menu in a Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

How is it possible to create a vertical menu on the left side of the window in Visual Studio (in a wpf) with xaml like the one in http://www.wpftutorial.net/? I try the code:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Black">
```

but it does not the task, since it presents a horizontal menu on the top.

It is not required to be done definitely by the control menu. If any other control with similar appearance is appropriate, it is acceptable.

Comment: Do you have a `DockPanel` around the `Menu`?

Comment: Yes, I do, it cannot work otherwise.

Comment: you can use the accepted answer, and create your own or https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/MaterialMenu that is ready to use

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Sure, just change `MenuItem.ItemsPanel` to use a Vertical StackPanel instead of the Default Horizontal one

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

</Menu>
```

Comment: @arjacsoh If the Menu is the last item that gets added to the DockPanel, then by default it will stretch to fill all remaining space. Either set `LastChildFill="False"` on your DockPanel, or add another element after the Menu. The following is a good link for getting an idea of the different WPF layouts: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFLayoutQS.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Accepted anwer is good. But it is a long way to get a good side bar working. you can use this control if what you need is a working menu now.

https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/MaterialMenu

you can install it from nuget too.

here is an example

```
<materialMenu:SideMenu HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Menu"
                           MenuWidth="300"
                           Theme="Default"
                           State="Hidden">
        <materialMenu:SideMenu.Menu>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Border Background="#337AB5">
                        <Grid Margin="10">
                            <TextBox Height="150" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18"
                                Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontWeight="Bold">Welcome</TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <materialMenu:MenuButton Text="Administration"></materialMenu:MenuButton>
                    <materialMenu:MenuButton Text="Packing"></materialMenu:MenuButton>
                    <materialMenu:MenuButton Text="Logistics"></materialMenu:MenuButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </materialMenu:SideMenu.Menu>
    </materialMenu:SideMenu>
```

Comment: Although this is a nice project, "working now" is a bit of a stretch (I tried it) and it doesn't do what the OP asked, which the accepted answer does. OP asked for a menu, not a sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the ItemsPanel using Style (which I feel is much more wpf-ish)

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Menu" x:Key="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
<Window.Resources>
```

the *VerticalAlignment="Center"* is there for beautification purposes, you can definitely skip it.

then in the menu code

```
<Menu Style="{StaticResource Horizontal}">
    ...
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the solution didn't work for me in ModernWPF, so instead I used multiple menus in a vertical StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem />
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem />
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```