# WPF - Possibility to loop through usercontrols?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm new to wpf and got stuck when I wanted to show different UserControls depending on different object's file extensions.

I have a menu sidebar like this (the tabs are hidden, so it is the illusion of a menu):

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="BtnSource">
    <Button FontSize="16"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Background="{DynamicResource UIColour6}"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Command="{Binding MenuButtonClick}"
            CommandParameter="SOURCE">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Foreground="White" Content="Source"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</ListBoxItem>
```

For every tab I need submenus like this:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1"
            Height="590"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Width="Auto"
            Visibility="{Binding SourceTabPageVisibility}">
    <TabItem Header="Source" Visibility="Hidden">
        <ContentControl Background="Transparent">
            <!-- Grid necessary because otherwise tabcontrol content can only be set once-->
            <Grid>

                <!--SUB MENU TAB PICTURE SOURCE -Corel-->
                <TabControl Grid.Column="1"
                            Height="590"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Visibility="{Binding SourceCorelTabPageVisibility}">
                    <TabItem Header="TestCorel"
                             Visibility="Hidden">
                        <ContentControl>
                            <local:UserControl_CorelDrawFormat />
                        </ContentControl>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>

                <!--SUB MENU TAB PICTURE SOURCE -ADOBE-->
                <TabControl Grid.Column="1"
                            Height="590"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Visibility="{Binding SourceAdobeTabPageVisibility}">
                    <TabItem Header="TestAdobe" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <ContentControl>
                            <local:UserControl_GeneralSettings />
                        </ContentControl>
                    </TabItem>

                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
```

I have a ViewModel with Code-behind which controls what is shown and when it is shown. The code-Behind does work, I debugged it several times. My problem is in fact, that when the dependent UserControl should be shown (the code-behind works, it has the right parameters etc..) WPF always shows the last `TabControl` of my `SubMenu`.

I read there is a possibility to do it with triggers, but I think that would be to extensive, because I have to many UserControls and every UserControl has a lot of different settings as properties. Does anyone know if there is a nice solution to "loop" through the UserControls? I want to achieve that I can switch between the objects and depending on their "FileExtension", I want to see the suitable UserControl with settings.

Here is a bit of the code-behind:

```
Private Sub MenuClickMethod(p As Object)

    Dim lParameter As String = p.ToString

    Select Case lParameter

    Case "SOURCE"
        SourceTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Visible
        ProfileTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Hidden
        ConvertTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Hidden
        TargetTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Hidden
        ReportTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Hidden

        'For showing the submenus depending on their  FileExtension
        If SourceTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Visible Then
            If SelectedProfile.SelectedSourceFile.FileExtension.Equals(".ai") Then
                SourceAdobeTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Visible
            ElseIf SelectedProfile.SelectedSourceFile.FileExtension.Equals(".cdr") Then
                SourceCorelTabPageVisibility = Visibility.Visible

            End If
        End If
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Kind Regards,

Laura

Comment: Just a thought about the design in general... what about using a sidebar menu instead of building the *illusion of a menu* (sounds more expensive to me than some triggers). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932060/create-a-vertical-menu-in-a-wpf for a way to change the menu orientation.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I wanted the sidebar to look a specific design and with the ListBox etc it was easier to achieve it. The sidebar is not really the problem, i think even if i would have used the MenuControl, my problem with the different UserControls would be the same. But that is my guessing as I am new to WPF.

Comment: How *"different"* are your different user controls? Is it really an individual appearance or is it just about displaying a different icon with some text?

Comment: The UserControls are not just icons with text. Each UserControl is different and has different Properties.

Comment: Do you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your properties (`SourceTabPageVisibility` and the others...)?

Comment: Generally, for a debugging problem, you should provide a full example on stackoverflow so others can actually try it out and reproduce your problem... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @grek40 Yes I do implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just guessing - what could be the problem - even with all your information. So maybe clean up your code first and use a `ValueConverter` to show and hide `Control`s depending on the File-Ending of your DataContext.

`IValueConverter`:

```
public class FileExtensionsToVisbilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string FileExtensionToShow
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(string.Equals(FileExtensionToShow, value.ToString()))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converter:FileExtensionsToVisbilityConverter x:Key="ShowIllustratorConverter" FileExtensionToShow="ai" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl Grid.Column="1"
                Height="590"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="Auto"
                Visibility="{Binding SourceCorelTabPageVisibility}">
        <TabItem Header="TestCorel" Visibility="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.FileEnding, Converter={StaticResource ShowIllustratorConverter}}">
            <ContentControl>
                <local:UserControl_CorelDrawFormat />
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

If you really stepped through everything - you should be able to identify what you're missing.